# jQuery select all items with id attribute and having a given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What i'm trying to do is to select all items where ID attribute starts with a given string but also having a class. For example i have this:

```
<div id="test-id-1" class="test"></div>
<div id="test-id-2" class="test selected"></div>
<div id="test-id-3" class="test"></div>
```

so i'm trying using something like this:

```
jQuery('div[id^="test-id-"].selected').trigger('click');
```

but it doesn't work. It should return only the second item in my example. How can i do this?

Many thanks in advance, :)

Comment: That should perfectly work: http://jsfiddle.net/jG8LV/.

Comment: Works fine for me to -> http://jsfiddle.net/YL7vT/ ... did you remember to wrap that in a document ready function?

Comment: Thanks VisioN, your example works, but in my code, the click event is not being triggered. I've binded the click event to the items so when any of them are clicked, then they do some actions and it works. But when using this: jQuery('div[id^="test-id-"].selected').trigger('click') that actions are not being fired

Comment: Can you show the code where you bind your click element? Maybe the bind happens after or is not properly written?

Comment: @adeneo the selector is inside another binding, something like this: jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]#act_showall').bind('change', function () {jQuery('div[id^="test-id-"].selected').trigger('click');})

Comment: A jsfiddle with a bind and the trigger("click") still working : http://jsfiddle.net/jG8LV/1/

Comment: @FidoBoy : are you sure the callback in change is properly called ? Maybe it's not the trigger("click") the problem but your bind on change

Comment: Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jG8LV/2/

Comment: As you can see it's not being triggered :(

Comment: ID is the most efficient selector... `'input[type="checkbox"]#act_showall'` is pointless to put inefficient prefixes in front of ID...just use the ID

Comment: you are right, @charlietfl but even doing that way, it doesn't work, see my code in jsfiddle

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/jG8LV/7/ doesn't work, and can't understand why... any ideas?

Comment: fiddle doesn't work for 2 reasons, syntax problem, and you set code not to be wrapped in load event...works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/jG8LV/9/. Sounds like you aren't wrapping your code in `document.ready`

Comment: From the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery): *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."*

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl you are right. Put your comment as a proposed answer and i'll give you the points. Thanks. Many hours coding, a bit tired and i doesn't saw the problem... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't been wrapping your code in `document.ready` which means if code is run before the html exists it will not bind handlers to non existent elements. Using the `ready` event wrapper assures that elements exist when code fires

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to trigger a click event is:

```
$('div[id^="test-id-"].selected').click();
```

Also remember to ensure that the element is actually loaded when you execute this code.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qy5Yc/